# Installing Driver for Matrox M9140 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, graphics, xorg, resolution, matrox

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit

Graphics Card: Matrox M9140

Monitor: Dell UltraSharp U2312HM 23"

Driver Location: http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/support/drivers/download/?cid=MTE2MTM3NQ==&id=574

I've been trying and failing to install the driver from the official Matrox site for my Ubuntu installation. My resolution only has 640x480 option. Needless to say I need something better. I keep getting the following error when I run the .run file that I downloaded from the Matrox website for the driver installation:

```
ERROR: Xorg 6.9, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3, 7.4, 7.5 or xserver 1.9, 1.10, 1.11, 1.12 or 1.13 not found. Please update Xorg.
```

As far as I can tell, I have both Xorg and Xserver installed. I've run the following commands to check:
`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core`

`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg`

`sudo apt-get install xorg`

and the output always says "xorg is already the newest version". I do not have a /etc/X11/xorg.conf file. But I didn't get the impression that that is a problem? When it asks me to choose a folder for the installation I just choose the default `/home/[my_username]/`.

In the README for the installation under "Troubleshooting" I don't see the error listed, but it does mention I need some files such as `/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/m9x_drv.so`, which I do not have. This looks like a file that the installer should be installing, no? I've Googled this to and no luck with any information on it.

Of the only two threads I could find with the above error message, one is in German (http://debianforum.de/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=147997) and one is in French ([just remove the space, I can only post two links per post :-(] http ://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=1136951) and neither seemed to give me a decent solution.

Output of `lspci | grep -i VGA` is:

`01:00.0 VGA compatible  controller: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. M91XX (rev 01)`

I'm not very experienced messing around with this particular area of Ubuntu and my shenanigans have already resulted in a clean install. Your guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Matrox readme file states that the driver works till Xorg 1.13 and works for Ubuntu 13.04. So the best bet for you would be to keep on Ubuntu 13.04 and urge Matrox support to provide updated drivers to work with Xorg 1.15 and Ubuntu 14.04.

Other option could be downgrade Xorg server to 1.13 with Ubuntu 14.04. This can actually work by pinning xserver-xorg* packages to raring release (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) and downgrading xserver-xorg* packages. However, I would not recommend that unless you are familiar with pinning and comfortable with package manipulations. If you are determined to do that I could provide precise steps to do that though there is no telling if it could cause something else to not work correctly.

Comment: Ahh, I missed that. The versioning of Xorg confuses me. Thanks. I don't like either of those options really.... I just ordered a cheap Nvidia card which has support listed on this page: http://www.howopensource.com/2012/10/install-nvidia-geforce-driver-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04-using-ppa/ I imagine I will have a much easier time which this?

Comment: Yeah, so, Nvidia 650 graphics card arrived today, popped it in and I didn't even need to install any drivers for it. The resolution was perfect from the startup. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Good solution to get better hardware... For Xserver versions for each release check [xserver-xorg-core](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xserver-xorg-core) package version.